# Mixed LTR and RTL text in a TextBox control

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a plain TextBox control in my WinForm application, and I type a string with mixed English and Farsi text (mix of LTR and RTL). When the TextBox RightToLeft property is set to Yes, it works fine on UI as expected, but when I get the Text property of the TextBox, the string is not what the control shows, and is completely different/wrong.

Here's a screenshot of how the text looks inside the Textbox control (right) and what the Text property returns (shown in a MessageBox).

[image]

How can I fix this? I expect Text property to return the same thing that is displayed on the UI.

Comment: The Text property doesn't care about right-to-left order, it is purely a rendering artifact.  You are getting unexpected output from the message box because it renders left-to-right.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass `MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading | MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign` to the `options` argument of `MessageBox.Show` to have the message box both align its text right and also render the entire message box with its text right-to-left:

```
MessageBox.Show("تست English-mixed جمله ...",
                "عنوان Title",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.None,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading | MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);
```

Result:
[image: Sample Output]